# How are big clojure projects organized?

Tags: file, class, methods, clojure, namespaces

In most programming languages you often have a "namespace > files > classes > methods" or similar organization. How is this done in clojure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is roughly:

```
namespace > files > vars
```

Note that:

- Namespaces are frequently defined in a single file, but don't have to be (you can use multiple files to define a namespace)
- vars can contain anything: functions, Java objects, data, macros etc. Most of the time, they will be either functions or top-level data literals
- Namespaces are dynamic: they can be modified at runtime. This gives you quite a lot of flexibility to organise your code in different ways if you want to (you can generate and populate your namespaces programatically for example)

See also:

- http://clojure.org/namespaces

Answer (score 0):

Clojure namespaces are java packages, so most Clojure programs are organised much like a java program would be, at least up to the package level.

After the package level I see many Clojure programs tending to be flatter than their Java counterparts.

Comment: Clojure namespaces are often used akin to java packages but they are definitely differently implemented with different semantics. See the [clojure.lang.Namespace](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/d0c380d9809fd242bec688c7134e900f0bbedcac/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Namespace.java) java class.  Clojure does have the concept of [libs](http://clojure.org/libs) which are made available as java resources and usually make available one clojure namespace.